# Android IMAP and MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, imap

I have an android application which fetches an email through IMAP and save in a MySQL table but sometimes what I see in records is this:

```
SGkKClNlbnQgZnJvbSBteSBWZXJpem9uIFdpcmVsZXNzIFBob25lCgotLS0tLSBSZXBseSBtZXNz
YWdlIC0tLS0tCkZyb206ICJBbm9ueW1vdXMgTWFpbCIgPGluZm9AZW1haWxhbm9uaW1vLmVzPgpE
YXRlOiBXZWQsIEp1biAyOSwgMjAxMSAxMDoyOCBwbQpTdWJqZWN0OiBLcmlzdGluYS5oaQpUbzog
IkVtYWlsQW5vbnltb3VzIiA8c3RpbmFtY2NveUB5YWhvby5jb20+CgpEZWFya3Jpc3RpbmFBbiBh
bm9ueW1vdXMgdmlzaXRvciBzZWxlY3RlZCB0aGUgZm9sbG93aW5nIG1lc3NhZ2UgZm9yIHlvdSA6
IDpoaQoK
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you'd need to show us at least a bit of code.

Comment: Is it a part of fetched email?

Comment: $link=mysql_connect("localhost","*********","*********");
mysql_select_db("critica",$link);

$respuesta=$_REQUEST['respuesta'];//mail's body sent by android and imap
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];//sent by android
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$sql = "UPDATE respuestas SET respuesta='$respuesta' WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close($link);

Comment: Some email messages are base64-encoded, and then the raw bodies tend to look like that. You need to either take care of the content-type and encoding yourself or get a library to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like base64 encoding. It is part of MIME and perfectly normal unless I'm very much mistaken.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME